# Get distance and velocity from discrete accelerometer data

Tags: python, scipy, distance, accelerometer, velocity

I know there has been a number of questions and answers on this topic, but none of them has helped me to understand how to approach the problem. So my set-up is: I have accelerometer data (clean from the gravity part), and I'd like to calculate from the given sample velocity and distance. The data is discrete, say, `dt = 20ms`, and `acc = [...]` is the array with samples.
I understand that I need to integrate the array to get velocity, but the integration gives me a single values, doesn't it?

```
velocity = scipy.integrate.simps(acc, dx=dt)
```

How do I use this value to get the distance afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = dv / dt
```

ie

```
a x dt = dv
```

Integration :

```
a[i](t[i+1] - t[i]) = v[i+1] - v[i]
```

ie

```
v[i+1] = a[i](t[i+1] - t[i]) + v[i]
```

After computing v, you can compute x :

```
x[i+1] = v[i](t[i+1] - t[i]) + x[i]
```